# The cursor should be freed up after use with #close

Tags: android

I'm using this code for Android but when I debug I'm seeing this error:
`the cursor should be freed  up  after use with #close`

This line has the error:

> ```
>  cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLECa, new String[]{ key_RoWid ,Key_GroupName}, null, null, null, null, null);
> ```

```
  public List<ListAdapterdb> Getall() {
        List<ListAdapterdb> dataList = new ArrayList<ListAdapterdb>();
       db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= null;
         cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLECa, new String[]{ key_RoWid ,Key_GroupName}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ListAdapterdb data = new ListAdapterdb();
               //data.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                data.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
                // Adding contact to list
                dataList.add(data);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return dataList;

    }
```

Comment: do you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to call `cursor.close()` when you're done dealing with the data.

```
try {
    ListAdapterdb data = new ListAdapterdb();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // data.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        data.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
        // Adding contact to list
        dataList.add(data);
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close()
}
```

Comment: There's no need to `try/catch/finally` block here.

Comment: this line iam see force close:

     cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLECa, new String[]{ key_RoWid ,Key_GroupName}, null, null, null, null, null);
dont inside while

Comment: also you can try `try (Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user", null)) {} ...` for example, java will use tryResourceClose feature: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 3):

### The most beautiful and elegant solution is to use Kotlin's `.use` extension

Here is an example:

```
cursor.use { cursor ->
    ...  //do whatever you need with the cursor
}
```

The point is that the `.use` extension will close the cursor for us **automatically**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this code to that line:
`@SuppressLint("Recycle")`

Comment: Please don't do this, try to fix the issue instead.

Comment: Try to use } finally {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                cursor?.close()
            }
        }